# Primes above $2$ in cyclotomic fields

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

I would be interested to know if there are any heuristics for how often it is the case that there is exactly one prime above $2$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$, where $\zeta_p$ is a primitive $p^\text{th}$ root of unity, and $p>5$ is a rational prime.

For example, by standard Galois Theory, $2$ is inert whenever it is a generator of the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$ which is believed to happen infinitely often (by Artin's conjecture on primitive roots as pointed out in the comments).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you asking about the (conjectured) **density of primes** such that $2$ is primitive root modulo $p$? If so take a look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @reuns! I was interested if there are any heuristics for the other situations in which there is precisely one prime above $2$.

Comment: That's the only case